# Amazon mws access denied for european marketplace

Tags: python, boto, amazon-mws

I'm trying to pull competetive prices from amazon mws using boto.
When I try to do it for US marketplace it works perfectly fine, bun when I try to do it using European endpoint it returns

> boto.mws.response.AccessDenied: AccessDenied: Unauthorized 
>    Access denied

Here is the code Im using

```
connect = connection.MWSConnection(aws_access_key_id=access_key,
`                                  aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
                                    host="mws-eu.amazonservices.com")
connect.SellerId=sellerId
product = connect.get_competitive_pricing_for_asin(ASINList= ["B01HETFQA8"],
                                                  MarketplaceId="A1PA6795UKMFR9")
```

Again, it works fine for US marketplace. Im registered as a seller in both US and Europe. Im getting marketplace IDs from this page
https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_Endpoints.html

Any help is greatly appretiated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Amazon Europe MWS Python Boto Connection AccessDenied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234242/amazon-europe-mws-python-boto-connection-accessdenied)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This questions has already been answered here:
[Amazon Europe MWS Python Boto Connection AccessDenied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234242/amazon-europe-mws-python-boto-connection-accessdenied).

But to reiterate, find your `connection.py` file for boto and at **line 269** change:

```
kw.setdefault('host', 'mws.amazonservices.com')
```

to

```
kw.setdefault('host', 'mws-eu.amazonservices.com')
```

By default Boto is routing to **Amazon US MWS endpoint** `mws.amazonservices.com` whereas you are looking for the **Amazon EU MWS endpoint** which is `mws-eu.amazonservices.com`

A full list of endpoints for other countries / geographical regions is available here http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_Endpoints.html

You can also see Boto's default `connection.py` file here:
https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/mws/connection.py#L269